# loop over file_put_contents triggers occasional "failed to open stream" warnings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, warnings

I have a php script that takes a while and thus wanted to report to an AJAX listener where we are ... so my php has something like this:

```
<?php
...
    while (something == true) {
        // lots of loops and work here to do
        file_put_contents('progress-info.txt',$progress_info);
    }
...
?>
```

In my javascript, I read this info into a div:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    ...
    setInterval(function () {
        //load data from file and display in element id="progress"
        $('#progress').load('/progress-info.txt');
        }, 1000); //every second
    ...
</script>
```

While this works well for the most part of the progress, **occasionally** (out of 10,000 loops maybe 3 to 5 times) I get a "failed to open stream: invalid argument" warning. So it's not the name itself (or missing slashes) - I rather suspect an occasional access conflict since two loops are running on the same file, one writing to it, the other (should be) only reading from it.
Is this because the jQuery load function locks the file while loading?
If so, what are my options to avoid this conflict? 
I tried to keep the file open in php and then truncate it before writing to it again, but this filled it up with NULLs and made it longer and longer in each loop - not sure what I could do about this issue either.
Any pointers are most appreciated!

Comment: i suspect a db would be more efficient

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure, but there may be some lock-functions out there (somewhere...), similar to how they work in `C++`. Making your own lock-function may be a bit complicated, considering how PHP and jQuery are really different...

Comment: thanks for the pointer - actually there IS a PHP similarity: For the file_put_contents function: LOCK_EX acquires an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing - I've set this meanwhile in my script and at least with a couple of test runs I didn't get any warnings for now.

Comment: @Dagon - yes, I've thought of doing this through a db, but liked the simplicity of the jquery .load function - I'm not so savvy on the javascript side ...

Answer (score 0):

For others running into similar issues - I had put an exclusive lock on the file, which can be done through a flag. Apparently there are several sub-processes executed with "file_put_contents" and an asynchronous javascript just reading the file could interfere:

```
file_put_contents('progress-info.txt', $progress_bar, LOCK_EX);
```

Adding the LOCK_EX flag resolved the issue of the random warnings produced during some of the executions of my loop.